# jQuery limit the number of elements shown to say like 5

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I got lets say this:

```
<ol>
<li>Content1</li>
    <li>Content2</li>
    <li>Content3</li>
    <li>Content4</li>
    <li>Content5</li>
    <li>Content6</li>
    <li>Content7</li>
    <li>Content8</li>
    <li>Content9</li>
    <li>Content10</li>
    <li>Content11</li>
    <li>Content12</li>
    <li>Content13</li>
</ol>
```

And the js something like this :

```
$("li").hide()
$("li:contains('Content')").show()
```

**Qusetion** :

Now How can i limit the number of shown elements to lets say around 5 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("ol li:contains('Content')").slice(0, 5).show();
```

or:

```
$("ol li:contains('Content'):lt(5)").show();
```

Comment: btw it should be slice(0,5) for 5 :P

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
$("ol li:contains('Content'):lt(5)").show();
```